# Using REGEX to remove the last leading zeros

Tags: regex

Is there a way to solve this problem using REGEX alone?

I have a string with, for eg.:

`123,4500` becomes `123,45`

`123,40500` becomes `123,405`

`123,000` becomes `123`

Knowing that we can make use of groups (i.e. `$1`, `$2`, etc...), is there a way to achieve this transformation with pure REGEX alone, without having to split the string at the `,`?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to match everything before ending zeros or remove these ending zeros?

Comment: what is the expected result for 100,000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This removes ending zeros and comma if followed by zeros only.

- Find: `,?0+$`
- Replace: `NOTHING`

**Explanation:**

```
 ,?  # optional comma
 0+  # 1 or more zeros
 $   # end of line
```

If you want to match everything before ending zeros, use:

```
^[\d,]+?(?=,?0+$)
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/8Cc44d/1)

Comment: I believe the result the OP is looking for is everything up to and not including what your regex matches.

Comment: @Booboo: May be, waiting for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

- Find ^([0-9,]*?)(?:,?0+)?$
- Group 1 is the result.

Explantion:

1. `^` Matches the start of the string.
2. `([0-9,]*?)` Capture Group 1: minimally match digits and commas up to what follows.
3. `(?:,0+)?` Optionally match an optional comma followed by one or more zeroes. This handles the case where the string has no trailing zeroes and nothing needs to be "replaced".
4. `$` Match the end of the string.

[See Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/woEMJn/3/)

The regex will replace *all* trailing zeroes. If, the string consisted of `000`, for example, Group 1, will be the empty string. If you really mean to keep at least one zero, then use:

```
^([0-9,]+?)(?:,?0+)?$
```

```js
let tests = [
  '123,450',
  '123,40500',
  '123,000',
  '123',
  '000'
]

for (let test of tests) {
    test = test.match(/^([0-9,]+?)(?:,?0+)?$/)[1];
    console.log(test);
}
```